# Rails 4 attr_accessor doesn't work across multiple methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attr-accessor

My model looks like this:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :start_time

  def start_time
    self.start_time = Time.now
  end

  def elapsed_time
    end_time = Time.now
    elapsed = end_time - self.start_time
  end

end
```

I want to measure the elapsed time, and `self.start_time` exists within the `start_time` method. However, in my `elapsed_time` method, `self.start_time` is nil. Why is that?

I am using rails 4.1.0 and ruby 2.0.0.

Comment: It looks like you are calling `elapsed_time` which defines `end_time`, then calling start_time, which would then end up being later than `end_time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `start_time` when the job object is created using initialize:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :start_time

  def initialize
    self.start_time = Time.now
  end

  def elapsed_time
    end_time = Time.now
    elapsed = end_time - self.start_time
  end

end
```

If you don't want `start_time` to be tied to when the job is initialized, then you need to create an instance variable to hold the start time, and reference that when you call the `elapsed_time` method:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :start_time

  def start_time
    @start_time = Time.now
  end

  def elapsed_time
    end_time = Time.now
    elapsed = end_time - @start_time
  end

end
```

Comment: The `attar_accessor` here is not needed, unless the user wants to be able to override @start_time outside the method for some reason. Leave it out and both methods still work. Depending on what is the expected behavior of the class, it might actually be bad from an encapsulation standpoint, no?

Answer (score 0):

`Beartech`'s answer is right, but let me explain why:

> [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) creates `setter` & `getter` methods for your
>   model. Just like how db attributes are defined, these create the
>   methods which you call on an object (`@object.method`), meaning they
>   are only created when your object is created
>
> Your problem is that you're relying on `attr_accessor` to persist
>   between object instances, which means the data won't persist between
>   requests. As `beartech` explained, the way to fix this is to somehow
>   "store" the data inside the `start_time` method, which is best done
>   when you initialize the object / class